# Short story about an astronaut who comes back to earth and lives a few seconds in the future?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, astronauts

What I remember is that this astronaut comes back to earth and for some unknown reason lives (experience time I should say) 13.6453837 seconds (I don't know this number exactly) in the future. So he becomes isolated and distant from his wife, since he already knows what's gonna happen inmediately after she speaks or does anything.

I can't remember the author, maybe Asimov, maybe Clarke. Dunno.
Please help!

Comment: Can you remember anything else? When you read it? If it was newly released? The names of any of the characters?

Comment: As Liath says, we're going to need some more details. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. It was in an anthology with time travel related stories. They set up rules to protect him. In one scene some family member of him doesn't follow the rule, resulting in the astronaut running into him where he was a few seconds or minutes before. The anthology also contained a story about a "very slow time machine" travelling backwards in time one second per second. It had a blueish cover I think. I read it between 1995-2000 I think, but I think is is older.

Comment: What I remember is that this astronaut comes back to earth and for some unknown reason lives (experience time I should say) 13,6453837 seconds (I don't know this number exactly) in the future. So he becomes isolated and distant from his wife, since he already knows what's gonna happen inmediately after she speaks or does anything.

Comment: @Hothie Exactly! do you remember something else? Could it be by Ray Bradbury?

Comment: I only find this, but this is another anthology with the slow time machine. What was this site which tracks in what anthologies a specific story was published?
https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/698910.The_Very_Slow_Time_Machine

Comment: @Hothie Now that I forcing my brain to remember, I think it may well be Brian Aldiss... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I remember a similar story (and, similarly, have no clue what it was) about a kid who went into a cave and was "out of sync" in the same manner... maybe it's the same story? Would have been something I read in grade school (90's)

Comment: @WernerCD The german tv series DARK also has a very similar plot about a cave

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe this is "Man in his Time" by Brian Aldiss, which involves a man out of time-sync with the rest of his family, and as the following quotes illustrate, causing a lot of trouble for his family.

> Janet told him apologetically, "You'll have to excuse us.
>   My husband did reply to you, but he's really not prepared to
>   meet people yet."
>
> "When did he reply, Mrs. Westermark? Before he heard
>   what I had to say?"
>
> "Well, naturally not but his life stream... . I'm sorry, I
>   can't explain."
>
> "He really is living ahead of time, isn't he? Will you spare
>   me a minute to tell me how you feel now the first shock is
>   over?"

And later:

> "Mr. Stackpole," Janet said sharply. "Can you please keep
>   to the point without being insulting? Will you tell me why
>   what happened was not an accident? I understand now that
>   when I looked through the study window I saw my husband
>   suffering from a collision that to him had happened three and
>   something minutes before and to me would not happen for
>   another three and something minutes, but at that moment I
>   was so startled that I forgot"
>
> "No, no, your figures are wrong. The total time lapse is
>   only 3.3077 minutes. When you saw your husband, he had
>   been hit half that time 1.65385 minutesago, and there was
>   another 1.65385 minutes to go before you completed the.
>   action by bursting into the room and striking him."

Comment: Yes. Thats at least the story I mentioned. But I'm not the questioner. :-)

Comment: I remember the bloody nose scene vividly! Also, that a scientist was constantly taking notes in order that he would remember to say the things the astronaut had already responded to - if that ever didn't happen the astronaut became disoriented or depressed...